# Return a react element containing a value from an array according to another array of integer

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have two array that contains an integer and strings like this.

```
let intArr = [4,3,2,1]
let player = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
```

and the sum of intArr will always be the same as player's length

how do i return return a div as much as each number in intArr with player's value inside the div

expected :

since intArr index 0 is 4, the first div should be like this

```
<div>
   <div> a </div>
   <div> b </div>
   <div> c </div>
   <div> d </div>
</div>
```

and then for index 1 of intArr which is 3, it should return like this

```
<div>
   <div> e </div>
   <div> f </div>
   <div> g </div>
</div>
```

and so on

Comment: pass the both array into the html page and use 2 `for` loop.

Comment: Are you asking how to use loops? Are you asking how to create elements with Javascript? Are you asking how to look up an index of an array? What have you tried, and what are you having trouble with? What do you mean "return a div"?

Comment: I'm trying to return a react component with divs inside it and asking how to loop the two array together so it can get the value just like how i put the expected result in the question. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need to group your letters:

```
let intArr = [4,3,2,1]
let player = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

let acc = 0
const groups = intArr.map(len => {
  acc += len
  return player.slice(acc - len, acc)
})
```

The `groups` now has a value of `[['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g'],['h','i'],['j']]`

Then we just output them like this:

```
return(
  <>
    {groups.map((group, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
            {group.map((letter, j) => {
              return <div key={j}>{letter}</div>
            })}
        </div>
      )
    })}
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, `intArr` defines the *slice* or *chunk* length for each group in `player`.

You can get the result you want like this...

```js
let offset = 0;
const slices = [];
for (const len of intArr) {
  slices.push(player.slice(offset, offset + len);
  offset += len;
}
```

You can iterate this in JSX to get your *divs*...

```jsx
{slices.map((slice, sliceIndex) => (
  <div key={sliceIndex}>
    {slice.map((p, pIndex) => (
      <div key={pIndex}>{p}</div>
    ))}
  </div>
))}
```

[image: Edit happy-blackburn-d02rf5]

---

If `player` and `intArr` are state values, you may want to wrap this in a [memo hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) so it recalculates if state changes.

```js
const slices = useMemo(() => {
  let offset = 0;
  const arr = [];
  for (const len of intArr) {
    arr.push(player.slice(offset, offset + len);
    offset += len;
  }
  return arr;
}, [player, intArr]);
```